# addEventlistener function gives error in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, mixitup

I have the following code which is used for a mixitup filter, this code regulates the input from an input range and sets it to a checkbox which is checked it works in every browser except for internet explorer (tested in ie11). I think it has something to do with the initial function.

```
var p = document.getElementById("range"),
    res = document.getElementById("output");

p.addEventListener("input", function () {

        $("output").html(p.value);

    var classes = "";   
    var minimal = 0;
    var maximal = p.value;
    $("input[type='range']").attr({'data-filter': "."+ maximal});
    $("input[type=checkbox].budget").val('.'+maximal);

    $( ".active" ).each(function( index ) {

      var thisClass = $(this).attr("data-filter");
      if (thisClass == '#mix.activiteiten') {
      } else {
          if (thisClass != 'undefined') {

            classes += thisClass + ',';
          }
      }
    });
    if (classes.length > 0) {
        var replaced = classes.replace('undefined', '');

        var matching = 0;
        var arrClasses = replaced.split(",")
    }


}, true);

p.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var $show = $('#FilterContainer').find('#mix.activiteiten').filter(function(){
        var price = Number($(this).attr('data-budget'));
        if (classes.length == 0) {

            return price >= minimal && price <= maximal;

        } else {
            for (index = 0; index < arrClasses.length; index++) {
                var thisValue = arrClasses[index].replace('.', '');

                if ($(this).hasClass(thisValue) && price >= minimal && price <= maximal) {

                    matching = 1;
                    return (price >= minimal && price <= maximal);

                }

            }   
        }

    }); 
        $('#FilterContainer').mixItUp('filter', $show);

}, true);
```

`

Comment: can i have a clue what is the "output" in the 4th line is it the custom tag used in ur page?

Comment: IE mostly uses attachevent instead try that.

Comment: Why do you mix jquery with plain JS event handling?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... by using the jQuery On, you can ensure better response across browsers and versions.

```
var p = document.getElementById("range"),
   res = document.getElementById("output");

    $("#range").on("input", function () { 
       ...    
    }, true);

    $("#range").on("change", function() {
       ...    
    }, true);
```

Comment: Does this work cross browser, most important ie 10 and 11, chrome, firefox and safari?

Comment: I use this quite regularly cross-browser.  If you want earlier versions of IE, use the 1-dot version otherwise the 2-dot version.  Two is more streamlined, as support for earlier versions has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

In older IE attachEvent method works instead of addEventListner

see [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in a cross-browser approach, try creating a function that handles the feature detection for you.  Here's one way that might help as a starting point:

```
function registerEvent( sTargetID, sEventName, fnToBeRun ) 
{
   var oTarget = document.getElementById( sTargetID );
   if ( oTarget != null ) 
   {
      if ( oTarget.addEventListener ) {   
         oTarget.addEventListener( sEventName, fnToBeRun, false );
      } else {
         if ( oTarget.attachEvent ) 
         {
            oTarget.attachEvent( sOnEvent, fnToBeRun );
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note that this function makes a few assumptions that you may wish to expand in in order to incorporate this into production code, such as error checking, fallback to attribute based event handlers, and so on.  Still, it may serve as a proof of concept.

Also, those claiming that IE predominately relies on attachEvent are referring to older versions of IE.  Starting with IE9, addEventListener is not only supported, it's recommended for IE.  To learn more, see:

- [How to detect features, rather than browsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh273397(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Use feature and behavior detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff986088(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [IECookbook: Compatibility guidelines and best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg130949(v=vs.85).aspx)

The [IE Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/) is a good way to stay up-to-date on the latest news and best practices for IE.  (For example, here's the entry talking about why you should use `addEventListener` instead of `attachEvent`.)

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

P.S. If 'addEventListener' doesn't seem to be working for you, trying adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the first line of your HTML file.  To learn more, see [How to enable standards support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699338(v=vs.85).aspx).

P.P.S. If you create a personal library of such functions, you can greatly reduce the amount of time it takes you to incorporate common tasks into new projects.